# How to make WordPress turn my posts into objects of a different class than WP_Post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'd like to create a subclass of `WP_Post` and add some "model functionality" to it. How can i force WP to create objects of that child class instead of WP_Post itself, when i query for my custom post type?

**Example:**

Let's assume i have two custom post types: `Book` and `Review`. Each Book can have many Reviews. On my Book, I want a method to sum up all its reviews. I'd define the following class:

```
class Book extends WP_Post
{
    public function reviewsSummary()
    {
        // Retrieve all reviews for $this book
        // Sum up their ratings
        // Return that sum
    }
}
```

Is there a way, for example when calling `register_post_type()`, to force WordPress into casting all posts of type "book" into my `Book` class instead of `WP_Post`?

Could look something like this:

```
register_post_type('book', [
    …,
    'class' => Acme\Models\Book::class
]);
```

Comment: You can override methods and properties of parent class that exist already 
looking here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php

Comment: I'm not asking how to override a method, but how to make WP turn my posts into objects of a different class than `WP_Post`…

Comment: ah, ok, so instead of creating post object using WP_Post class, it would use Book class? 
For  register_post_type, there is no option of overriding WP_Post class in that manner. 
Even in get_post() function, there is no option to override WP_Post. 
You could however instead of using get_post(), create function get_book(), and then instead of using WP_Post class, use Book class. 

I am aware that you want to automatize it that way, however, some things like overriding menu walker class, or widget class are not easy applicable for posts.

Comment: register_post_type is used to create or modify the custom post type. Try with walker class.

Comment: Thanks, @niklaz! Can i make it work automatically for example when i issue a `WP_Query`?

Comment: @user3040610, can you please give some more detail on your suggestion? How can i use the walker class to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: @jsphpl, quickest and probably only solution in this case would be to extend `WP_Post` as you were meant to, then to call it: 
`global $post; $book = new Book( $post );` and then to use it like extended object, or to clone and modify `get_post()` also i.e. `get_book()`, where you instead of `WP_Post` use  `Book`

Comment: Oh, and I found now similar case :) 
https://resoundingechoes.net/development/extending-the-wp-post-class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but maybe this is a way for that what you want:

Look here at line 3617 -> [query.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src//wp-includes/query.php#L0)

```
// Convert to WP_Post objects
if ( $this->posts )
    $this->posts = array_map( 'get_post', $this->posts );

if ( ! $q['suppress_filters'] ) {
    /**
    * Filter the raw post results array, prior to status checks.
    *
    * @since 2.3.0
    *
    * @param array    $posts The post results array.
    * @param WP_Query &$this The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
    */
    $this->posts = apply_filters_ref_array( 'posts_results', array( $this->posts, &$this ) );
}
```

Maybe you can use the filter hook `apply_filters_ref_array` and run your own function if the post type is a book.

```
// in your filter function
if ( book ) {
   return array_map( 'get_book', $posts );
}
return $posts;
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that one!

Comment: Okay so the array passed to that filter contains `WP_Post` objects already. But still, it is a place where i can hook in and replace them.